# Regular expression (getting number, C#)

Tags: c#, regex

Please help me to write Regular expression on C# for getting Int64 value from string:

> "NumberLong("634461051992965873")"

my string  includes **NumberLong** part;

so as result must be **634461051992965873**

Thank you!)))

Comment: I have no experience in regular expressions:)

Comment: you do not need a regular expression to do this, you just need to call Int64.parse on the string

Comment: Does the string to be parsed include that text called "NumberLong"?

Comment: Yes!))) String includes NumberLong )))

Comment: What can other strings look like? How about `NumberLong('634461051992965873')`, `NumberLong23("634461051992965873")`, `NumberLong("maybe 634461051992965873 24141242")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string Temp = "Hax00r L33t";
string Output = Regex.Replace(Temp, "[^0-9]", "");
long num = long.Parse(Output);
```

Comment: thank you! but it is not what I need))) I have string "NumberLong("634461051992965873")" and from this string I want to cut integer number;)

Comment: this should be Int64.Parse(text)

Comment: @RiaD Ok, you reduced the length of the string. But in the OP's case, `int.Parse` won't work for reasons you should know. ;-)

Comment: @Alex R:, yes, you are right. @Edward83:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844461/return-only-digits-0-9-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

[`long.Parse("634461051992965873")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3.aspx) 
does the job, but you could check [`long.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zbx0k66.aspx) too.

Comment: It is not what I need))) String includes NumberLong:)

Answer (score 1):

```
String txt = "634461051992965873";
int nbr;

if(Int64.TryParse(txt, out nbr)) {
    // text can be converted to Integer
}
```