# I need to remove duplicates from a List<>

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<CreditCard>`, a property of the credit card is `CreditCardNumber`, which is a string. Unfortunatly, it can be `1234 1234 1234 1234`, or `1234123412341234`, which are both the same number.

I need to go through and remove these duplicated items. Could someone assist?

Comment: how can `1234` be the same like `1234123412341234` ?

Comment: @gdoron it's about the spaces

Comment: he meant `"1234 1234 1234 1234"` is the same as `"1234123412341234"`.

Comment: Is `CreditCard` a class you can modify?

Comment: @Andrei. Well... after someone edit it's clear.

Comment: @Craig what about other properties of CreditCard? If we have two credit cards with same number, but other properties will be different - which card to pick?

Comment: ps. it's probably best to remove all spaces from the string when you assign a value to CreditCardNumber; otherwise you'll incur overhead every time you compare this number, and presumably the spaces are meaningless once in your program.  Alternatively you can keep a copy of the original input in one variable, but cache the converted copy in another - tiny memory hit for a small performance gain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

public List<string> GetUniqueCardNumbers(List<string> cardNumbers)
{
    // First replace the spaces with empty strings
    return cardNumbers.Select(cc => cc.Replace(" ", ""))
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Dammit, you beat me to it. :)  Yeah, use this. :)

Comment: Technically, the OP wants a distinct list of `CreditCard`, not `string`

Comment: Is "12 34123 4 123 41234" the same as "1234123412341234"?

Comment: @Andrei. Good question but I believe in credit cards where you put the white space doesn't matter too much...

Comment: But this changes the collection. I assume OP don't want to modify the list, he just wants to compare "ignore-whitespace". Maybe he wants to keep the space-numbers like `1234 1234 1234 1234` or the first of each duplicate-list.

Comment: What do you do with your list of strings? Join them back onto the list of CreditCards? Seems messy to me.

Comment: Imho the best approach would be a custom `IEqualityComparer<CreditCard>` for `Enumerable.Distinct`.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to remove the spaces from the card number on input so you only have to perform the cleaning operation once:

```
    public class CreditCard: IComparable<CreditCard>
    {
        string creditCardNumberClean;
        string creditCardNumberOriginal;
        public string CreditCardNumber
        {
            get 
            { 
                return this.creditCardNumberOriginal; 
            }
            set
            {
                this.creditCardNumberOriginal = value;
                this.creditCardNumberClean = value.Replace(" ", "");
            }
        }
        public CreditCard(string creditCardNumber)
        {
            this.CreditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
        }

        public int CompareTo(CreditCard other)
        {
            return this.creditCardNumberClean.CompareTo(other.creditCardNumberClean);
        }
    }
```

But if that's not possible you basically want to perform a string comparison on the card number just mutating the number to remove all spaces before the comparison:

```
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[]{"1234 1234 1234 1234", "1234123412341234","9999 9999 9999 9999"});
            SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>(list, new CreditCardNoComparer());
            foreach (string s in set)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public class CreditCardNoComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return x.Replace(" ", "").CompareTo(y.Replace(" ", ""));
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

```
//version using overridden GetHashCode and Equals methods as per @lazyberezovsky's comments 
public class CreditCard
{
    long creditCardNumberClean; //given the card number is numeric this is the most efficient way of storing it
    string creditCardNumberOriginal;
    public string CreditCardNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.creditCardNumberOriginal;
        }
        set
        {
            this.creditCardNumberOriginal = value;
            this.creditCardNumberClean = long.Parse(value.Replace(" ", "")); 
        }
    }
    public CreditCard(string creditCardNumber)
    {
        this.CreditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        CreditCard other = obj as CreditCard;
        return 
            other == null 
            ? false 
            : this.creditCardNumberClean.Equals(other.creditCardNumberClean);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.creditCardNumberClean.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Best solution - get rid of various representation of keys. But I'd probably go with Equals (compare numbers) and GetHashCode (number code).

Comment: Thanks @lazyberezovsky; agreed overriding Equals and GetHashCode's the better approach; I'll update my example. . .

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove white space from every one
2. Use `Distinct();`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `EqualityComparer` for `CreditCard` which removes whitespace and use `Enumerable.Distinct` to remove the duplicates:

```
public class CardComparer : IEqualityComparer<CreditCard>
{
    private readonly Regex re = new Regex(@"\s+");

    public bool Equals(CreditCard x, CreditCard y)
    {
        return re.Replace(x.Number, "") == re.Replace(y.Number, "");
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CreditCard obj)
    {
        return re.Replace(obj.Number, "").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
IEnumerable<CreditCard> unique = sourceList.Distinct(new CardComparer());
```

Comment: It doesn't quite return a list.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to determine what constitutes "equal". If it's as simple as removing embedded spaces, then you can use one of the previous solutions that removes the white space and calls `Distinct`. Otherwise you'll have to create an equality comparer and pass it to the [Distinct overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<CreditCard> distinctCards = cards
  .Select(card => new {
     card, 
     ccn = card.CreditCardNumber.Replace(" ", string.Empty)
  })
  .GroupBy(x => x.ccn)
  .Select(g => g.First().card) //group has at least 1 member, so First() is safe
  //.ToList()   ???
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract only the numbers from any string, in your case you can only make a replace of the space character for a empty character, for a more complex string format you can use the next code for get only numbers. You can check this answer: [get only digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844479/1819490)

```
string justNumbers = new String("asd123 f3 4.34-3 ".Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Then you will have only the digits of your `CreditCardNumber` and you can search for duplicated values.