# How to filter out numbers from a string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string of the following form for instance -:

```
String str = "The game received average review scores of 96.92% and 98/100 for the Xbox 360 version";
```

and I want the output as follows -:

```
Output = "The game received average review scores of % and / for the Xbox version"
```

and I want to be able to filter out any number that's there in the string whether its a decimal or a floating point number, I tried using a brute force way of doing this like this -:

```
String str = "The game received average review scores of 96.92% and 98/100 for the Xbox 360 version";

String newStr = "";

for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; ++i){
if(!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
   newStr += str.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(newStr);
```

but this doesn't solve the purpose for me, how to go about solving this problem?

Comment: You might check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19169192/1578604) which is basically the opposite of what you're looking for. With some tweaking, you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps use something like this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*\\s*", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following [**`String#replaceAll`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) call to replace all numbers (followed by 0 or more spaces) by an empty string:

```
str.replaceAll("\\d+(,\\d+)*(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*", "");
```

Comment: this doesn't work for such kind of string : "The App Store offered more than 775,000 apps by Apple and third parties." it leaves a "," in between

Comment: You example also has `%` and `/` left behind in the string.